# Audio flicking at back port

Tags: sound

In my Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit system, whenever I connect speaker at back audio port of my system the audio is flicker(in case when volume is 100% of both system volume and  application volume that playing audio e.g. music player).

And when volume decrease somewhat, 60% or less it's stop flicking.

But on front port is not happening, it working fine?

And in sound setting there is flicking like shown in image, it continuously changing from analog output and headphone and vice versa. That cause audio flicking.

[image: Screen Shot]

and output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
 0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb44000 irq 43
 1 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb40000 irq 16
```

Is back port is defected or something else?

Comment: It seems like the "flickering" is the sound card rapidly detecting you inserting/removing an output device from your front audio port (the "headphone" jack).  Try leaving a device stuck in the front port.  Does this "flickering" between devices still occur when you set the system output level below 60% as you've said, or does that only resolve the *audible* flicker?  As a quick solution, you might want to investigate forcing a particular output channel for your system's audio (i.e. disabling automatic detection when plugging a pair of headphones/speakers in).

Comment: When device plug at front port then there is no audio from back port. It plays at front port.

Comment: Does the menu itself keep flickering when the volume is under 60%?

Comment: Sometime or hardly.....

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to me when I connect the headphones to the headphone jack. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the audio type in bios from HD to AC97 (even though the front panel is configured for HDAudio on the MB) and the issue went away.